# Remote website trigger a local action

Tags: python

I have large video files (~100GB) that are local on my machine. I have a non-local website where I enter information about the video file. In addition, I need to get the checksum of the video file (and I do not want to manually trigger the script locally and copy and paste the value). To get a checksum of the video file, I have a script I can run as `$ checksum.py <video file>`.

How would I trigger the local script through the web interface? In other words, I want to be able to enter the PATH of the video file and click Submit on the web app, and it will locally trigger the script, and (after the checksum has finished), insert that value into the web app/database. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot trigger anything unless your local script is continuously listening for some kind of data feed (like a fixed URL serving an XML/JSON feed of paths) which is, IMHO, over-complicating your system.

You could also use a Java applet ran locally instead of a remote website, but you'll have to sign it to be able to read local files, and it might not be what you're looking for.

Think of it: it's all about security. Would you like any web server to trigger scripts in your local machine? I certainly wouldn't.

IMHO the best solution is to trigger the script manually which will send the data to your web server.

Answer (score 1):

In general browsers run in a sandbox that has very limited access to the OS.  In particular you can't run shell scripts from a browser. As I see it you have two options:

1. Adapt your checksum.py script to send the checksum info directly to your website using the urllib2 calls, or pipe the results to a "curl" command. (No browser involved.)
2. Rewrite checksum.py as JavaScript using the FileReader class.  This will probably be convoluted, slow, and won't work in Internet Explorer.